# Vagrant and Virtual Box keep getting set to Aborted

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am having an issue with vagrant and virtualbox in which I am able to `vagrant up` fine but after a few minutes (sometimes it's 5 minutes sometimes it's an hour) my virtualbox gets set to an 'ABORTED' status.  I am unsure of why this happens.

I'm using VirtualBox 5.1.28 and the most recent version of vagrant (2.0.0).  I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Below is the output of my `vagrant up` command.  I've noticed there is a disconnect retry thing but I don't know why that is there.  It is not there for my coworkers.  I've done some googling already and all the people with the same problem never make it out of the disconnect retry loop.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Specific bridge 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)' not found. You may be asked to specify
==> default: which network to bridge to.
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en1: Thunderbolt 1
3) en2: Thunderbolt 2
4) bridge0
5) p2p0
6) awdl0
==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
    default: Which interface should the network bridge to? 1
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33306 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/jdavis/hts_vagrant
    default: /app/localhost/html => /Users/jdavis/projects
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
```

Comment: vagrant seems to run fine, it launches the shell provisioning which is hanging, you need to check from there